# $E_{y}(B_{u})=y$ for a Brownian motion $B_{s}$

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I'm trying to follow the following statement on pg 325 Durrett's book on probability where he states that the following holds by symmetry:

$$E_{y}(B_{u})=y $$

The subscript $y$ implies that we are assuming that almost surely our base point is $y$, that is $\omega(0)=y$. In which case, I think of $B_{u}$ as sending $\omega \mapsto \omega(u)$, why is the best guess for this $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the measure $P_y$ the process $(B_u -y)_{u\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion starting from $0$. Now the symmetry: The process $(-(B_u -y))_{u\geq 0} = (-B_u + y)_{u\geq 0}$ is also a Brownian motion starting from $0$. But this is overkill.

$B_u -y$ has centered normal distribution with variance $u$, thus this distribution is symmetric, this means $B_u -y$ has the same distribution as $-(B_u -y)$.

For a symmetric random variable $Z$ we have $E(Z) =E(-Z) = -E(Z)$, hence $E(Z) = 0$.

This means in this case $E_y( B_u -y ) = 0$, which is your statement.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you, I guess one can think of $y$ as $B_{0}$.

Comment: Yes, under $P_y$ is $B_0 =y$ almost surely.